# Bootstrap 4 text align

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to create a card with a footer that contains a date on the left side and a price on the right side. Both properties have to be on the same line. I tried with grid system but it doesn't work.

Here is a sample :

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="card-deck">
    <div class="card">
        <img src="http://lorempicsum.com/futurama/568/300/1" class="img-fluid">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer">
            <div class="col-xs-7 d-inline-block">Date</div>
            <div class="col-xs-5 d-inline-block">price</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to keep the divs containing Date and price because it will be more things inside.
Thanks

Comment: Please read the [Bootstrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/). This is not a problem with text-right. There is no longer `-xs` used in Bootstrap 4. Also, "*columns must be the immediate children of rows*". `.col-` that are not placed in `.rows` will simply stack vertically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="card-deck">
        <div class="card">
            <img src="http://lorempicsum.com/futurama/568/300/1" class="img-fluid">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-6">Date</div>
                  <div class="col-6 text-right">price</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I need to use col-xs-6 for divs to keep them inline on small devices. With this code it doesn't work.
Also, do you think there is another way to do it without adding row ? Because it adds marges on both sides

Comment: @Zak there is no col-xs-* class in Bootstrap v4.
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Comment: You are right, I didn't notice that. Thank you
But, I have some marges on the left and right side with the row class, I tried marging -15px but it doesn't work. Is there a way to make it fit the card ?

Comment: Thank you Vadim, that's what I need